# Chemical Formulae and the Periodic Table of Elements

Tags: nomenclature

Reading about heavy water, I have found that the chemical formula for it can be written 2H<sub>2</sub>O or D<sub>2</sub>O.

> Deuterium is an isotope of hydrogen that is found in large quantities in water, more than one atom per ten thousand hydrogen atoms has a deuterium nucleus. The isotope is denoted “2H” or “D”, and is normally known as “heavy hydrogen”. Deuterium is used in a number of conventional nuclear reactors in the form of heavy water (D<sub>2</sub>O), and it will probably also be used as fuel in fusion reactors in the future (Source: [ScienceDaily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/05/090511181356.htm)).

Encyclopædia Britannica [says the formula can be](https://www.britannica.com/science/deuterium) <sup>2</sup>H<sub>2</sub>O.  Is this correct?

2H (or <sup>2</sup>H) = D is interesting to me as D is not in the periodic table of elements.

I thought that formulae should be formed using the symbols within the periodic table.  What **are** the rules surrounding these chemical formulae?

Comment: Yes the Encyclopædia Britannica is correct. The 2 exponent before the H means that the atomic mass number is 2. Since H has one proton, that means there is one neutron also. // Deuterium is often denoted with a D, and Tritium with a T. The bare $\ce{^4He}$ nucleus is also known as an $\alpha$ particle. No other element has multiple symbols for isotopes.

Comment: @MaxW - So is it more correct to use superscript 2 or is it down to style requirements in articles?

Comment: If i writing about using H isotopes for some purpose then using D and T is fine. If I were just discussing various isotopes (eg $\ce{^{23}Na}$) in general  then I'd use the $\ce{^2H}$ and $\ce{^3H}$ forms for consistency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this entry in the IUPAC Gold book

https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/D/D01648.html

the symbol for Deuterium is H together with the isotopes notation.

However deuterium and tritium are routinely indicated by D and T respectively. Their use is dictated by the framework. Besides nuclear reactions, when only straightforward chemical properties* are considered, it is convenient to use a single letter rather than H and super/sub-scripts.

In organic nomenclature, while writing names for molecules, the presence of deuterium is signalled by the symbol (d).

*note that isotopic effect might however affect chemical properties at fine levels. The toxicity of heavy water is a notable striking example.